# My game doesn’t seem to play the scenes in the correct order

Tags: unity-game-engine

But my scenes don’t go in order and I’ve tried disabling some scenes and it skips scene 1 and 3 but when I disable some of the other scene like 4,5,6 it still skips 1 and plays 2,3 and like it skips scenes and I don’t know what to do and I couldn’t find anything on YouTube I might of disabled something in setting but I don’t know since I’ve only been at it nearly a month

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1)
```

and

```
SceneManager.LoadSceene(1)
```

Comment: Without code its hard to help, please try again :^)

Comment: The thing is ive tried to put in the code I used but it kept saying formatting error and I just dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The order of BuitIndex is defined in build Window.
To get that one go to `File->Build Settings` menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> In the window that pops-up, you can see all scenes that you have added to build. If you don't see your current scene, there is a button on the lower left that says `Add Open Scenes`. And in here, you can click-&-drag the scenes in list, to change their build index.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. It's quite a unique problem